# How to prevent implicit conversion from string to scientific notation when storing a qvd?

Tags: type-conversion, implicit-conversion, qlikview

I am a Qlikview user. I have a field in my data which is a 15 digit number. When I pull my data from server i cast it as a string and use it. But when I store my data in a qvd, it gets converted into scientific notation and the data becomes useless. How can I prevent this?

Comment: So you are using table: LOAD text(field) FROM Database; STORE table into table.qvd(qvd); and it still saves it as number?

Comment: @mickeger - yes. That is the exact problem.

Comment: I learnt doing this. I just save it as a Char(100). Now when i reload it, it comes out as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can display numbers whose length is greater than 14 without the scientific notation. You can either change the data type to text during the fetch or split the field into two parts.

Comment: I often need to join that data to other data fields. so splitting will not help me.

Comment: I learnt doing this. I just save it as a Char(100). Now when i reload it, it comes out as expected. Thanks!